# Sherman-Morrison inverse formula

Tags: matrices, inverse

I've read a paper in which the authors said that they use the "Sherman-Morrison inverse formula". While I know the Sherman-Morrison formula, I couldn't find anything about the inverse of said formula.
Based on the equations in the paper the formula should look something like this:
$$ A^{-1} + uv^T = A - \frac{Auv^TA}{1 + v^TAu}$$

Does this formula exist? Can anyone point me in the right direction in terms of literature?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula and the beautiful article http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities/

Comment: My guess is that they don't mean the inverse of the formula, but rather that the formula finds inverses